# Is there a way to find out the guild name with only the ID?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In order to use my bot, I want the server to need a license. These servers that have a license are stored in an array. Unfortunately, it's only the ID. Now I would like to issue a command: "& sv-id [ServerID]". He currently gives me whether the ID is in the list or not. Next, he should send me the name of the guild. Is there a way to get the guild with the ID? The command is sent as a private message. My code (not ready yet):

```
if message.author.id == client.AppInfo.owner.id:
    if message.content.startswith(CONFIG.PREFIX + "sv-id"):
        if len(message.content) == 25:
            serverID = message.content[7:25]
            if int(serverID) in CONFIG.AllowedServer:
                guildWithID = client.guilds.id == len(message.content)
                await message.channel.send(":white_check_mark: Server Name: **" + guildWithID.name + "**\n"
                                           "  ServerID: **" + str(serverID) + "**\n")
            else:
                await message.channel.send(":x: Dieser Server existiert nicht, oder ich bin auf diesem Server nicht autorisiert!")

        elif len(message.content) != 25:
            await message.channel.send(":x: Bitte benutze **" + CONFIG.PREFIX + "sv-id [ServerID]**")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If your bot is in the guild, you can use [`Client.get_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild). Otherwise, you can use [`Client.fetch_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_guild).

For more information about retrieving a specific model by ID, see [the FAQ](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-get-a-specific-model).

Answer (score 1):

There is [`Client.get_guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_guild).  I believe it will only get guilds which your bot has already joined.

```
guild = client.get_guild(id)
```